# How to convert start and end dates of rows into monthly chunks using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

This is the dataset I have

```
  id      start        end
0  A   1-Jan-19  31-Dec-19
1  A   1-Jan-20  31-Dec-20
2  B  13-Jun-19  19-Nov-19
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ["A", "A", "B"],
           'start': ["1-Jan-19", "1-Jan-20", "13-Jun-19"],
           'end': ["31-Dec-19", "31-Dec-20", "19-Nov-19"]})
```

This is the dataset I need

```
   id      start        end
0   A   1-Jan-19  31-Jan-19
1   A   1-Feb-19  28-Feb-19
2   A   1-Mar-19  31-Mar-19
3   A   1-Apr-19  30-Apr-19
4   A   1-May-19  31-May-19
5   A   1-Jun-19  30-Jun-19
6   A   1-Jul-19  31-Jul-19
7   A   1-Aug-19  31-Aug-19
8   A   1-Sep-19  30-Sep-19
9   A   1-Oct-19  31-Oct-19
10  A   1-Nov-19  30-Nov-19
11  A   1-Dec-19  31-Dec-19
12  B  13-Jun-19  30-Jun-19
13  B   1-Jul-19  31-Jul-19
14  B   1-Aug-19  31-Aug-19
15  B   1-Sep-19  30-Sep-19
16  B   1-Oct-19  31-Oct-19
17  B   1-Nov-19  19-Nov-19
```

The data is grouped by id and time chunks are spread across months. I have tried to use the resample and bfill Pandas methods to no success. Is it possible to do this with Pandas or do I need a work around method by doing a merge on a date series and filtering where dates overlap?

Thank you

Comment: Rows with index values 0 thru 11 in your expected dataset seem to
be a "result" of source row with dates *1-Jan-19* and *31-Dec-19*.
Then (rows with index values 12 thru 17) result from row with dates *13-Jun-19* and *19-Nov-19*.
But what with row with both dates from year 2020?
What should be the "result" of this row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from defining a function to be applied to each row:

```
def expDates(row):
    d1 = pd.to_datetime(row.start)
    d2 = pd.to_datetime(row.end)
    stList = [d.strftime('%#d-%b-%y') for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq='MS')]
    if len(stList) == 0:
        stList.append(row.start)
    elif stList[0] != row.start:
        stList.insert(0, row.start)
    endList = [d.strftime('%#d-%b-%y') for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq='M')]
    if len(endList) == 0 or endList[-1] != row.end:
        endList.append(row.end)
    return pd.DataFrame({'id': row.id, 'start': stList, 'end': endList})
```

Then apply this function, saving the result as a list of DataFrames:

```
tbl = df.apply(expDates, axis=1).tolist()
```

And the last step is to concatenate these DataFrames:

```
pd.concat(tbl, ignore_index=True)
```

In my opinion, this solution is less "pythonic" and more "pandasonic"
then all others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ["A", "A", "B"],
           'start': ["1-Jan-19", "1-Jan-20", "13-Jun-19"],
           'end': ["31-Dec-19", "31-Dec-20", "19-Nov-19"]})

df1["start"] = df1["start"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%b-%y") )
df1["end"] = df1["end"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%b-%y") )
df1["rows"] = abs((df1["start"]-df1["end"])/np.timedelta64(1,'M')).astype(int)
df_new = pd.DataFrame([df1.ix[idx] 
                       for idx in df1.index 
                       for i in range(df1.ix[idx]['rows'] +1)])
df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)
groups = df_new.groupby(["start", "end"],as_index = False)
grouped_df = groups.apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True)).reset_index().drop('level_0',axis = 1)
grouped_df["start"] =grouped_df.apply(lambda row : row["start"]+  relativedelta(months=row["level_1"]), axis =1)
grouped_df.drop(['level_1', 'rows'], axis =1 ,inplace = True)
grouped_df
```

I am assuming that you skipped the processing of the second input row.
If this is not the case, please let me know.

Input:

[image]

Output :

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKfXz.png]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think my solution is the elegant one. However, it returns your desired output. In the first step, I just import packages and make `df` data frame as you did.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': ["A", "A", "B"],
        'start': ["1-Jan-19", "1-Jan-20", "13-Jun-19"],
        'end': ["31-Dec-19", "31-Dec-20", "19-Nov-19"]
    }
)
```

In the second part, I iterate over every row in `df` data frame and try to make an items for the the second data frame - I have called it `df_2`. Items are stored in `data_items` list.

```
data_items = []
for id_, start, end in zip(df['id'], df['start'], df['end']):
    start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d-%b-%y')
    end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%d-%b-%y')
    start_dates = [dt for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start_dt, until=end_dt.replace(day=start_dt.day))]
    for i, start_date in enumerate(start_dates):
        if i == len(start_dates) - 1:
            end_date = end_dt
        elif start_date.month == 12:
            end_date = start_date.replace(day=31)
        else:
            end_date = start_date.replace(month=start_date.month + 1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        data_items.append(
            {
                'id': id_,
                'start': start_date if i == 0 else start_date.replace(day=1),
                'end': end_date
            }
        )
```

You can check, if the output in `df_2` is what you want to achieve.

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_items)
df_2[['id', 'start', 'end']]
```